# Trying to get value of a subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, subprocess, ip

I am creating a function to test connection and to get value but it is not working.
I'm using a grep to get only received value.

```
def testConnection(ip):
    
    TIMEOUT = 10
    args = ('sudo', 'ping', '-c', '1', '-q', ip, '|', 'grep -E -o', '"[0-9]+ received"', '|', 'cut', '-f1', '-d') 
    
    try:
        popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        popen.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT)
        
                   
        if (popen == 1):
            print(ip + " is up")
        else:
            print(ip + " is down")
            
                
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
        print(e)
        return False
        
    if(popen.returncode != 0):
        raise ServiceException()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use something like popen with a ping I prefer to count the number of "ttl" in the message as only one is displayed when the connection is successfully established. Then you just have to check if the readback value is equal to the parameter given in -c :

```
ping -c 1 {ip} | grep -c ttl
```

example of output in a shell :

```
$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.120 | grep -c ttl
1

$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.254 | grep -c ttl
0
```

Take care to read stdout and not the return value of popen to be sure that the ping did not time out.

Example :

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 {} | grep -c ttl".format(ip), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**Only args as a sequence**

```
args = ('ping','-c','1',ip)
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if "ttl" in p.stdout.readlines()[1]:
    # ping ok
else :
    # ping ko
```

Comment: When I use: grep -c ttl, I got an error: ping: invalid argument: 'ttl'
my code: args = ('ping', '-c', '1', ip, '|', 'grep', '-c', 'ttl')

Comment: Try to pass all the command in one string because popen is interpreting your others arguments as arguments of ping. Something like I edited.

Comment: Is it to avoid shell injection as described in the [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) doc? if yes, then you may have to only call ping as passing args as a sequence is only when you use program arguments. Please, see the only args section of my answer for a workaround.